# Phonegap - <a href> open in system browser

Tags: cordova, mobile, browser, href

I have a very big web page with many sub pages. Inside html code there is a lot of 's that leads to external pages. I have to transform this pages into phonegap app. Every link has to be open in system browser. I know that in phonegap I should use onclick="window.open(...) but is there any easier way in order not to have modify every singe  in my old code(there is hundreds of them)?

Comment: It is just an idea and it is not optimized. You may defined on event before click on links. This event will do window.open() and avoid link by returning false.

Comment: [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) plugin may be helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If every instance of the `<a>` can be overridden, and assuming you have jQuery, try binding all clicks on the `<a>` tags.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use InAppBrowser plugin

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

then you can use

> window.open('http://apache.org', '_system');

open in system browser!